# why can not I json_decode an array?

Tags: php

why can not I json_decode an array ?

the codes bellow has "\w" ,when I use json_decode , the php return null value, why? and how can I fix it ?

```
<?php
$str='[0,"^(\w)+$","Your email is unvailable"]';
$arr= json_decode($str,true);
var_dump($arr); // null
```

Comment: an array is a decoded json, and on top of that, that's not an array.

Comment: Did you try to use double slash in regexp?

Comment: I mean json_decode consider your \w as incorrent escape-encoded character.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, plain and simple: http://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In strings in JSON, backslashes have to be escaped; you want <sup>[(demo)](http://ideone.com/TCWg1V)</sup>

```
$str = '[0,"^(\\\\w)+$","Your email is unvailable"]';
```

There need to be four backslashes because php string literals require backslashes to be escaped as well.

Comment: An escape to escape to escape to escape a ``\``. Madness. :)